# Why does my state became array with dispatch action function as one of its elements?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have state in react hooks like this

```
const category = useState(props.catid);
```

state comes as a prop. when i log props.catid to console it only shows the value. But when i log category it will look like this

```
category state :  
(2) […]
​
0: 102
​
1: dispatchAction()
​​
length: 1
​​
name: "bound dispatchAction"
​​
<prototype>: function ()
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

I only need the value it should be updated from props too.

Comment: What is the initial value of `props`?

Comment: 102 is the initial value i only need that. When i log props.catid it shows but useState(props.catid) not working as needed

Comment: Can you add working code into the post, so that this problem is reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

`useState` hook returns an array, the first index *is* the state value, the second index *is* the function to update state. Common syntax is as follows:

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState(props.catid);
```

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

If the syntax is confusing, it is [array destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

If you only need the first value, omit the setter:

```
const [category] = useState(props.catid);
```

At this point I'll only make the comment that state is really useless now and you should just use the prop `catid`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are actually logging the return value of state, you will see the entire object along with its prototype

In general the useState returns an array with 2 elements. The first element is the state value and the second value is the setter to useState. Since useState is internally implemented over `useReducer` the setter is actually a `dispatchAction` function instance

The reason useState returns you an array is because you can destructure and names the field and setter whatever you like unlike in object destructuring

You can think of the above like

```
const categoryState = useState(props.catid);
const category = categoryState[0];
const setCategory = categoryState[1];
```

or simply

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState(props.catid);
```